# How to refer to internal document in CTHyperLink using Apache Poi?

Tags: apache-poi

I want to include a link that refer to an internal embedded document, so click on it will open the document.

If I set the target to an external source (like web url) it works fine:

```
String linkId = xdoc.getPackagePart().addExternalRelationship("http://www.website.hu", XWPFRelation.HYPERLINK.getRelation()).getId();
CTHyperlink cLink = myParagraph.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();   
cLink.setId(linkId);
```

And that is it, it works fine. I just created an externalrelationship with the target url and relationtype and passed it to the hyperlink.

Now I want to accomplish the same behaviour, but this time hyperlink should point to an internal document which resides in the docx under path `word/embeddings/test.docx`

```
//embedded part is the packagepart for the document
String linkId = xdoc.getPackagePart().addRelationship(embeddedPart.getPartName(), TargetMode.INTERNAL, XWPFRelation.DOCUMENT.getRelation()).getId();
CTHyperlink cLink = myParagraph.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();   
cLink.setId(linkId);
```

And this is where dead end comes: clicking on the link (the link popup shows the correct path inside docx) automatically change to path to and external one which points to my filesystem. So if my working directory is in `c:\myfile`  the link to my internal file inside docx `'word/embeddings/test.docx'` will be changed to `c:/myfile/word/embeddings/test.docx` which is wrong behaviour in my opinion.

I have tried to pass different arguments to addRelationShip() like TargetMode.EXTERNAL, WPFRelation.HyperLink..etc, but results the same and due to lack of documentation these are just trial and error.

So how should I refer to an internal document via hyperlinks?

Comment: How would you refer to an internal embedded document via hyperlink in `Word` `GUI`? This is simply not possible because it is not supported by a `Word` document. And `apache poi` cannot do what is not supported in `Office` document formats.

Comment: thanks, I didnt know that it us not supported by the Word itself.